# volatile variables and parallel streams in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented

For the Below code want to know whether the correct procedure is followed
for the java code , are there any missing points according to the java standards ?

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class CodeReviewTest {

    volatile Integer totalAge = 0; 

    CodeReviewTest(PersonDatabase<Person> personPersonDatabase) {
        Person[] persons = null;

        try {

            persons = personPersonDatabase.getAllPersons();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        List<Person> personsList = new LinkedList();

        for (int i = 0; i <= persons.length; i++) {
            personsList.add(persons[i]);
        }

        personsList.parallelStream().forEach(person -> {
            totalAge += person.getAge();
        });


        List<Person> males = new LinkedList<>();


        for (Person person : personsList) {
            switch (person.gender) {
                case "Female": personsList.remove(person);
                case "Male"  : males.add(person);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total age =" + totalAge);
        System.out.println("Total number of females =" + personsList.size());
        System.out.println("Total number of males =" + males.size());
    }

}


class Person {

    private int age;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    String gender;

    public Person(int age, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.age = age;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return this.lastName == ((Person)obj).lastName;
    }


}


    interface PersonDatabase<E> {

        Person[] getAllPersons() throws IOException;

    }
```

**Questions**

- Does the above code follow the standards by java ?
- Can I use better idioms?
- Can this implementation be improved for performance?
- Can the style / readability be improved?

Comment: First thing I see is that "Java" is a proper noun and therefore should be capitalized. :)

Comment: Ugh, NEVER catch and ignore an exception.  It's super poor style.  If you don't know what to do with an exception, you should probably not catch it at all and just let it propagate up the call stack.  Catching and ignoring `IOException` like you do is especially pernicious.

Comment: The title should indicate what the code does rather than what you want out of the code review. The code should be a real implementation of something and not hypothetical. A class or method name like `CodeReviewTest()` may indicate to some reviewers that this is a hypothetical question.

Comment: Can you put a different title explaining what you are trying to do here?

Comment: The title is changed , need reviews on the code implementation

Comment: `for(Person person : personList) { ... personList.remove(person); ... }` should crash with a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  Was this code ever run?  Or is it really just a test of the Code Review site.

Comment: The code does not break on parallel stream , but i wanted to know whether including parallel stream is correct or not

Comment: the for loop is wrong, i <= persons.length must be i < persons.length, otherwise you get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because length returns the number of elements, but since arrays are zero indexed you should iterate till n-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Errors

1. **Modify variable inside lambda expression:**
   You sure this code passes compilation? you have a lambda expression (`forEach()`) that modifies a variable. all variables that are used inside lambda expression are considered `final`.
   by the way, the whole calculation of `totalAge` can be converted to stream() processing using `map()` and `sum()`
2. **The `switch` statement:**
   there is no `break;` between the `case`s, so every female will also be counted as male.

## Standards

1. **gender:**
   Any reason why this property has no getter method?

## Best Practices

1. **equals():**
   does not protect from `NullPointerException` or `ClassCastException`
2. **Use enum :**
   whenever you have a finite closed set of valid `String` values. (like gender in your case). the advantages are that the literal value is specified only once, typos are getting detected by the compiler, and you can add properties and behaviors (=methods) to the enum values. in this case, perhaps the display message `"Total number of...` can be added as property?
3. **Converting array`[]` to `List`:**
   no need to iterate over the array. Use `Arrays.asList()` .
4. **Single responsibility principle:**
   The constructor of `CodeReviewTest` is doing all the calculations and printing the results. this breaks the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). meaning, there are multiple factors that require modifying the code in that one method: adding a new value to gender (yes, it's possible in today PC culture), sending the results in to another destination (for example, storing in DB), there are more.

## Readability

1. **Using `personsList` to hold all females:**
   This is confusing. imagine you are part of a dev team. your team member might need to modify the code you've written. they will assume that `personsList` holds all person objects.
2. **Using constructor to perform logic:**
   constructor has a fixed name that does not say what the method does. it is intended to initialize the object (= populate properties). even if your class has only one method, it is better to have a non constructor method with clear descriptive name.
3. **Comments:**
   there are none. nough said.

Comment: Yes, the `totalAge` lambda code would compile, because it a member variable (`this.totalAge += ...`), and `this` is final. (But the code is still horribly broken.)

Comment: The code does not break on parallel stream , but i wanted to know whether including parallel stream is correct or not

Answer (score 4):

Issues Sharon Ben Asher did not mention:

Because you're not using the index variable i to anything other than indexing the array you should use the for-each variant of the for loop to make the code cleaner. LinkedList is the wrong data type. Since you're only adding and never modifying the list and know the size you should use an ArrayList with correct initial size. Variables that are not changed should be marked final:

```
final List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList(persons.length);

for (Person person: persons) {
    personsList.add(person);
}
```

(Or better yet use the Arrays.asList for this particular use case).

The totalAge field is pointlessly volatile. It is accessed only in the constructor which means it can only ever be accessed by one thread.

Comment: it is also pointlessly defined `Integer`. should be defined as the primitive type

Comment: The `totalAge` field isn’t pointlessly volatile.  The `.parallelStream().forEach(...)` statement will run the lambdas in separate threads.  However, `volatile` doesn’t fix the problem, since the code will still be doing read-modify-write operations in different threads; atomic operations would need to be used.  Or simply using proper stream methods like `.sum()`

Comment: so is it fine to use volatile or not ?